# Cordova - Device Orientation events no trigger

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, phonegap

I try to implement in my application the use of a compass but the documentation of Apache Cordova says that the plugin is obsolete

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/

Follow the post they mention, record the events (compassneedscalibration, deviceorientation) as mentioned but never run.

https://blog.phonegap.com/migrating-from-the-cordova-device-orientation-plugin-8442b869e6cc

If I try to run navigator.compass or window.compass it mentions that it is undefined

I am currently using the Phonegap template with Vue
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-vue-f7-blank

Answer (score 0):

Did you removed the cordova plugin?

Comment: Hi Flavio. I don't added the plugin because the documentation say that is Deprecated